# Limiting distribution of generalized derangement

Tags: integration, limits, probability-theory, derangements, laguerre-polynomials

Suppose there are $N$ people in a party. Each of them brings $k$ gifts. When the party is over, each of them takes $k$ gift randomly. Denote $T$ is the number of gifts return to its original giver. Please find the limiting distribution with $N\to +\infty$ and $k$ fixed.

From this link [Generalized Derangement Problem with $k$ unchanged elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2526770/generalized-derangement-problem-with-k-unchanged-elements) , I find the generating function
$$f(u)=\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(k!)^N}{(Nk)!}(u-1)^{kN}L_k^N(\frac{x}{1-u})e^{-x}dx$$

However, I have trouble evaluate the coefficients for general $k$. I don't know much about the Laguerre polynomials.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, it has an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3866336/n-kids-with-k-balls-reshuffle-find-distribution-of-number-of-balls-brought?rq=1)

Comment: It turns out that I'm heading the wrong way. But I'll be grateful if anyone can evaluate the above integral.